# Determine tile identity of tile set displayed on Google Maps/OpenStreetMap

Tags: google-maps

I'm not sure if this is best way of approaching this, so I will explain where I'm coming from first.

I want to load data onto my webpage containing a map based off a lat/long point. The only way I know how to do this is to constantly be getting the a lat/lng point in the displayed map. Obviously this isn't very efficient since I either need to keep track of this point, or constantly be polling it. Each time I had the updated this point, I'd have to do some sort of processing to determine it's map location, which would add even more inefficiency. When I had that, I could then proceed to load my data.

My idea was that if I could pull down an id of map tiles of a particular region at a set zoom level, then I wouldn't need to do the crazy/complicated lat/lng processing. But, my stumbling block is that I don't know of any way this is possible.

Comment: So are you trying to find a map tile or a particular latitude/longitude point?  Either way, you should not have to poll continuously unless you are looking at a moving target.

Comment: I might understand better now.  Are you trying to load a map for an area that the user chooses?

Comment: Looking for some identifier for a map tile. If there are two tiles with some street intersection in each for example, I want to be able to do action X for the first tile, or action Y for the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the Quadtile?

**Google Map APi (v3) Quadtree visualized**

[image]

http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/quadtree/quadtree_intro.htm

Credit to Esa

Comment: Wow, that is awesome. Would vote you up but I got no rep!

Comment: There you go...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to pull tiles outside of the legitimate API methods.  You will likely get your access cut off if you do this. Anyway...

http://khm1.google.com/kh/v=85&x=19063&s=&y=24812&z=16&s=G

That's the URL from one Google map tile. You can find these by examining the browser activity in Safari or with the Firefox Firebug add-on.

Comment: Well the tiles are already going to be displayed on the page in whichever container I'm using so I won't have to do any extra work (pull tiles). I'm looking for a way to get an identifier of the centermost tile (if possible) displayed in the container.